# Understanding Matplotlib code for creating a figure

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization

I found a blog post that shows the street network orientation of 25 US cities using polar histograms: http://geoffboeing.com/2018/07/comparing-city-street-orientations/.

The author provided the code to reproduce the figure containing the 25 histograms (contained in full here: https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx-examples/blob/master/notebooks/17-street-network-orientations.ipynb).

I want to use the code to create a figure that shows only one city's histogram, but I get error messages when using fewer than 25 cities.

I have not used matplotlib before, so I assume the issue lies in the portion of the code that defines the number of columns and rows in the figure, but I am not sure how to edit it to do what I want.

```
# create figure and axes
n = len(places)
ncols = int(np.ceil(np.sqrt(n)))
nrows = int(np.ceil(n / ncols))
figsize = (ncols * 5, nrows * 5)
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows, ncols, figsize=figsize, subplot_kw= 
{'projection':'polar'})
axes = [item for sublist in axes for item in sublist]

# plot each city's polar histogram
for ax, place in zip(axes, sorted(places.keys())):
polar_plot(ax, bearings[place], title=place)

# add super title and save full image
suptitle_font = {'family':'Century Gothic', 'fontsize':60, 
'fontweight':'normal', 'y':1.07}
fig.suptitle('City Street Network Orientation', **suptitle_font)
fig.tight_layout()
fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.35)
plt.gcf().savefig('images/street-orientations.png', dpi=120, 
bbox_inches='tight')
plt.close()
```

Using four cities:

```
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-43-c59ecd43a7f0> in <module>()
     16 fig.tight_layout()
     17 fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.35)
---> 18 plt.gcf().savefig('images/street-orientations.png', dpi=120, 
        bbox_inches='tight')
     19 plt.close()

C:\PythonAnaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py in savefig(self, 
fname, **kwargs)
   1832             self.set_frameon(frameon)
   1833 
-> 1834         self.canvas.print_figure(fname, **kwargs)
   1835 
   1836         if frameon:

C:\PythonAnaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.py in 
print_figure(self, filename, dpi, facecolor, edgecolor, orientation, format, 
**kwargs)
   2265                 orientation=orientation,
   2266                 bbox_inches_restore=_bbox_inches_restore,
-> 2267                 **kwargs)
   2268         finally:
   2269             if bbox_inches and restore_bbox:

C:\PythonAnaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py in 
print_png(self, filename_or_obj, *args, **kwargs)
    510         renderer.dpi = self.figure.dpi
    511         if isinstance(filename_or_obj, six.string_types):
--> 512             filename_or_obj = open(filename_or_obj, 'wb')
    513             close = True
    514         else:

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'images/street- 
orientations.png'
```

Using one city:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-58-c59ecd43a7f0> in <module>()
      5 figsize = (ncols * 5, nrows * 5)
      6 fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows, ncols, figsize=figsize, subplot_kw= 
        {'projection':'polar'})
----> 7 axes = [item for sublist in axes for item in sublist]
      8 
      9 # plot each city's polar histogram

TypeError: 'PolarAxesSubplot' object is not iterable
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a single subplot, the number of rows and the number of columns of the grid is both `1`.

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1, figsize=figsize, subplot_kw= {'projection':'polar'})
```

You then need to remove any looping from your code, because `axes` is the only axes in your plot.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  Where is the looping that I need to remove?

Comment: If you only want one plot, you should not loop anywhere.

Comment: That makes sense, but I am not sure where to edit the code to stop it from looping.  Do you mean `axes = [item for sublist in axes for item in sublist]` and if so, what does it need to be?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your four cities example: create an `images` subfolder for it to save into. matplotlib doesn't create all the folders automatically if you provide a path that doesn't yet exist.

Regarding your one city example: remove the list comprehension if you're only doing a single plot using a single axis, as you don't need to flatten what would otherwise be a numpy array of axes objects.